# flutter unnecessary statement on call to stream cancel

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, analyzer

I have flutter code that creates a stream and cancels the stream during the dispose:

```dart
 @override
  void dispose()  {
    if (_playerSubscription != null) {
      _playerSubscription.cancel;
      _playerSubscription = null;
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
```

The problem is that when I submit the code to pub.dev the static analyzer emmits the following error:

`Avoid using unnecessary statements.`

The error is emitted on the line:

```dart
_playerSubscription.cancel;
```

I've check the code in async.dart and it uses exactly the same three lines that I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cancel()` is a method. You need to change it like so:

```
  @override
  void dispose()  {
    if (_playerSubscription != null) {
      _playerSubscription.cancel();
      _playerSubscription = null;
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
```